# wicket ajaxformcomponentupdatingbehavior get value of TextField by clicking button

Tags: java, forms, wicket

I have a form and there is a TextField. I added button to a form, different than the default submit. I want to use Ajaxformcomponentupdatingbehavior to get the value from the TextField after clicking the button next to the TextField.

My code looks like:

```
private String string;
...
public ..() {   
Form form = new Form("form") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit() { 
         //some code
};

add(form);
TextField textField = new TextField("string", new PropertyModel<String>(this,"string"));
 textField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
form.add(textField);
Button button = new Button("evalButton");   
form.add(button);
button.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onclick") {
            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {               
                System.out.print(textField.getValue());
             }
});
```

the value of the TextField is null, after clicking the button for the second time, I get the right value. How could I get the value of the TextField after one button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` doesn't do quite what you think. The behaviour is actually applied to the `TextField`, not to the button. Your code is updating the model of the button rather than the text. See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11410500/184998) for an example.

I've done this before for a postcode lookup button in an address form.  I used an `IndicatingAjaxButton' to push the entire form, and I disabled default form processing. I then grabbed the text input directly, pushed it through my validator which standardised the formatting, then processed:

```
final IndicatingAjaxButton lookup = new IndicatingAjaxButton("lookup", form) {
  @Override
  protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
    String code = postcode.getInput();

    code = (new PostcodeValidator()).convertToObject(code,
                    getLocale());

    ... Postcode lookup here


    target.add(ContactDetailsPanel.this);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
  }
};
lookup.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
add(lookup);
```